# Can I remove one booster from XGBoost model

Tags: xgboost

I have a xgboost model of 500 trees, and I want to exclude/remove a single booster (e.g., booster 450th) because this tree creates large bias on a subgroup of my sample.

I understand I can create predictions on each booster, and take a sum by excluding the prediction from boost 450th. But I need to update the model itself for further analysis.

This is what I have so far. Make the model into list, drop the element (booster).

```
Model = xgb.train(kwargs, num_boost_round = 500, dtrain=dtrain)
Model_lst = list(Model)
del Model_lst[450]
```

My question is how to make this list of boosters back to a xgb model such that all the methods and attributes can be used.

Or please let me know if this can be done in any other way. All comments are very well appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a workflow for modifying `xgboost.Booster` objects manually:

1. Save the booster object to a file in local filesystem using the [`Booster.save_model(fname)`](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/python/python_api.html#xgboost.Booster.save_model) method. Be sure to specify a `.json` file name extension, in order to get a JSON data. If you use any other file name extension, you'll get an Universal Binary JSON (UBJSON) file that will be useless in this case.
2. Make the edits to the booster JSON file either manually or programmatically. Here' you'd be deleting the 450th element from the related data arrays. See the XGBoost file specification, you'd need to modify several data arrays (level: advanced).
3. Read the modified JSON file back into a live booster object using the [`Booster.load_model(fname)`](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/python/python_api.html#xgboost.Booster.load_model) method.

> Or please let me know if this can be done in any other way.

You could export your XGBoost model in a standardized PMML data format using the [SkLearn2PMML](https://github.com/jpmml/sklearn2pmml) package, and make your edits against the PMML XML file. Will be much easier to do than editing the JSON file, becuase PMML data structures are human-oriented. For example, to disable a tree element, you would simply change its activating predicate from `<True/>` to `<False/>` (in comparison, with JSON you'd need to be modifying >5 data arrays).

Sure, using PMML is one-way street, because you currently can't load the PMML document back into a booster object. But if you're about to deploy the modified model in some application, then PMML is technically easier to work with (integration, prediction, verification) than native XGBoost.

Comment: Looks like it's the second question in a row where I've been advising PMML as a solid technical platform for solving a little more advanced XGBoost tasks. Did it work with feature importances?